# Django Rest Framework - Receive Primary Key in POST Response body

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I try to build a rest api with *Django Restframework*. In this Api i use a Model called `Event`.

**models.py**

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    key = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    host = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='host', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    host = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    key = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['url', 'key', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'subject', 'description', 'host']
```

**views.py**

```py
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def skills(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_key_values(TblClsOne=EventSkills, TblClsTwo=Skills, table_one_column_name="event_id",
                              table_one_fk_name='skill_id', table_two_column_name="skill_id",
                              table_one_filter_value=kwargs["pk"])


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(host=self.request.user)
```

When I want to see the Details from a event i call `GET /events/<id>/`

**GET /events/502/ Example**

```json
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/502/",
    "key": 502,
    "start_date": "2021-09-23T20:00:00Z",
    "end_date": "2021-09-23T21:00:00Z",
    ...
    "host": null
}
```

But if I create a new Event via `POST /events/`

I will receive empty fields for `key`and `url`.

How can I integrate the created values for these two fields? They are mandatory for navigating to the detail view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to return the object from `perform_create`, and override `create` and use the created object on the serializer again like this:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        obj = self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(self.get_serializer(obj).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(host=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new event serializer to use for the create method that doesnt set the key as read_only and use it for the create method. Overide the get_serializer_class in your view to select the correct serializer depending on the case.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action != "skills":
        return CreateEventSerializer
    return super().get_serializer_class()
```

As for the url I am guessing you are not getting it back because it is not a model field. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: thanks for your inspiration. Unfortunately I will not receive the key in the response body of the `POST /event/`. Have you any idea how this could work?